# Change the value of an animation and restart it

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I created a counter animation that increments for x seconds.
When the user arrives at the widget, the animation starts correctly via an initState.
I also created textfield begins and end to allow the user to update the start and end value and restart the animation.
Problem when the user pressed the button to restart the animation, it does not work.

PS: You can test the code if you want by copying the whole into a new project in main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ShowCounter(),
    );
  }
}

//
// The animation
//

class AnimatedCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  // Variables
  int startValue;
  int endValue;
  Duration timeAnim;
  Color color;
  double factor;

  // Constructor
  AnimatedCounter({
    int startValue,
    int endValue,
    Duration timeAnim: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    color: Colors.black,
    factor: 5.4,
  }) {
    this.startValue = startValue;
    this.endValue = endValue;
    this.timeAnim = timeAnim;
    this.color = color;
    this.factor = factor;
  }

  @override
  _AnimatedCounterState createState() => _AnimatedCounterState();
}

class _AnimatedCounterState extends State<AnimatedCounter>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animCounter;
  AnimationController _controller;
  String i;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // AnimationController
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: widget.timeAnim, vsync: this);

    // Animation
    animCounter = Tween<double>(
            begin: widget.startValue.toDouble(),
            end: widget.endValue.toDouble())
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
    ))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
              i = animCounter.value.toStringAsFixed(0);
            });
          });
    _controller.forward().orCancel;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Layout
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      '$i',
      textScaleFactor: widget.factor,
      style: TextStyle(color: widget.color),
    );
  }
}

//
// Display and layout
//

class ShowCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowCounterState createState() => _ShowCounterState();
}

class _ShowCounterState extends State<ShowCounter> {
  // Variable
  AnimatedCounter counter;
  int startvalue;
  int endValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startvalue = 0;
    endValue = 42;
    counter = AnimatedCounter(startValue: startvalue, endValue: endValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Counter animated"),
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                counter,
                Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: "Starting value"),
                          onChanged: (String string) {
                            setState(() {
                              startvalue = int.tryParse(string);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "End value"),
                          onChanged: (String string) {
                            setState(() {
                              endValue = int.tryParse(string);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text("Run"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // Desperate attempt to restart animation with new start/end value (not working)
                                counter = AnimatedCounter(
                                    startValue: startvalue, endValue: endValue);
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a globalkey of state, so that you can access method of state from parent widget.

You have to pass globalkey to that widget and then create a method from initstate content and call that method from parent widget.

following full code will help you more.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ShowCounter(),
    );
  }
}

//
// The animation
//

class AnimatedCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  // Variables
  int startValue;
  int endValue;
  Duration timeAnim;
  Color color;
  double factor;

  AnimatedCounter(
      {int startValue,
      int endValue,
      Duration timeAnim: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      color: Colors.black,
      factor: 5.4,
      Key key})
      : super(key: key) {
    this.startValue = startValue;
    this.endValue = endValue;
    this.timeAnim = timeAnim;
    this.color = color;
    this.factor = factor;
  }

  @override
  AnimatedCounterState createState() => AnimatedCounterState();
}

class AnimatedCounterState extends State<AnimatedCounter>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animCounter;
  AnimationController _controller;
  String i;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("object");
    super.initState();
    // AnimationController
    startanimation();
  }

  startanimation() {
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: widget.timeAnim, vsync: this);

    // Animation
    animCounter = Tween<double>(
            begin: widget.startValue.toDouble(),
            end: widget.endValue.toDouble())
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
    ))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
              i = animCounter.value.toStringAsFixed(0);
            });
          });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Layout
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      '$i',
      textScaleFactor: widget.factor,
      style: TextStyle(color: widget.color),
    );
  }
}

//
// Display and layout
//

class ShowCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowCounterState createState() => _ShowCounterState();
}

class _ShowCounterState extends State<ShowCounter> {
  // Variable
  AnimatedCounter counter;
  int startvalue;
  int endValue;
  GlobalKey<AnimatedCounterState> state = GlobalKey<AnimatedCounterState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startvalue = 0;
    endValue = 42;
    counter = AnimatedCounter(
      startValue: startvalue,
      endValue: endValue,
      key: state,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Counter animated"),
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                counter,
                Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: "Starting value"),
                          onChanged: (String string) {
                            setState(() {
                              startvalue = int.tryParse(string);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "End value"),
                          onChanged: (String string) {
                            setState(() {
                              endValue = int.tryParse(string);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text("Run"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                counter = AnimatedCounter(
                                  startValue: startvalue,
                                  endValue: endValue,
                                  key: state,
                                );
                                state.currentState.startanimation();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my response time.
Yes, your solution worked well.
But once your solution applied, it revealed a bug at the level of the manufacturer who could not pass the new value to the animation (in one time).
You have to press the submit button twice for the new values to be taken into account without my being able to explain it.